# Permission install Prestashop

Tags: php, permissions, web-hosting, prestashop

I've trouble in install of Prestashop 1.3.7 in my web host, i yet send all files, and when I enter in install i got this message in red: "Allowed to create new files or folders" like i haven't permission. But in Ftp program i saw that i've.

I found one solution in this web site:

http://ffct.cc/prestashop-allowed-to-create-new-files-and-folders/

And after I followed steps, two operations aren't found:

chmod and getcwd.

Someone knows if thats very important for the sequence of install ?? Or I can ignore in php file like site explain and install ??

Who can help me ?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: chmod sets the permission of a folder/file. So you must use it. Usually you are able to run chmod using the most important ftp clients.

Comment: But I saw using ftp program that all folders are 777, that's alright, but install can't go next